# Can you recommend a plugin or gem that generates a facebook-style message inbox using Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

I want a way for users to send and receive messages and to see them in an inbox similar to how it is done in Facebook: it shows the subject and knows whether the particular message was received or sent, and then clicking shows the entire thread.

I have been trying to use a single Message record with a UserMessage -- one for the sender, the other for the recipient -- but not exactly sure how to, for example, show all the messages for a User whether a recipient or sender.

Ideally, someone has already done this in a plugin or gem I can repurpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a very difficult task for you to handle.  We want to be able to send messages between users.  Let's say we have a `User` model that looks something like (for the sake of simplicity)

```
create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "username",        :null => false
    t.string   "hashed_password", :null => false
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "salt",            :null => false
end
```

and a `Message` model that looks like (also for the sake of simplicity)

```
create_table "messages", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "subject",       :null => false
    t.integer  "sender_id"
    t.integer  "recipient_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

and a `Msgcontent` model that looks like

```
 create_table "msgcontents", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "body",       :null => false
    t.integer  "message_id"
    t.integer  "sender_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

Now that you have those models set up, in your controller you might have something like.

```
def show_all_messages
    @sent_messages = Message.find_all_by_sender_id(params[:user_id])
    @received_messages = Message.find_all_by_recipient_id(params[:user_id])
end

def show_message_detail
    @thread = Msgcontent.find_all_by_message_id(params[:message_id])
end
```

Where `params[:user_id]` is the current user signed in and `params[:message_id]` is the message that you want to show in detail.  You can also combine the 2 variables into one variable, but you might want to separate it, it's up to you.  This way, in your view you can appropriately display all the messages that have been sent and received by a user.  I'm not going to write a whole view worth of code, but basically there's the `show_all_messages` that gets all messages that the user is a part of, and the `show_message_detail` will get the whole thread of the message.  I will leave this part to you :)

If you want to be able to tell whether a user has seen the message or not, you can add 2 fields to your `Message` model, which would then result into

```
create_table "messages", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "subject",              :null => false
    t.integer  "sender_id"
    t.integer  "recipient_id"
    t.datetime "sender_lastviewed",    :null => false
    t.datetime "recipient_lastviewed", :null => false
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

Now you will know the last date that the sender or recipient has looked at your message.  In your `show_all_messages` you would need to update your `Message` model to reflect the two columns you've added to your table.  Then to able to get the messages after the `_lastviewed` you need to use conditions in your code, which can be found [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html)

If you really want to find a gem, you can probably can with some diligent googling, however there are some very basic Rails (and database) concepts here that is essential for you to understand if you want to rely on your own knowledge for future development.

Comment: thanks for the thorough answer.  How will we be able to represent changes in status for the sender and recipient, for example, if they are different (one reads it, the other hasn't)?

Answer (score 0):

`has_mailbox` gem

is there to send messages between users, I'm testing it on my sample porject right now :)
and dont forget to add will_paginate gem in gem file because for now ha_mailbox gem shows error incase will_paginate is not in gem file. I think it is dependent on it